# Knockoutjs observable boolean returning strange results

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In my viewmodel, I have defined:
`self.myAreasEditMode = ko.observable(false);`

In my html, I have:

```
<div>
  editing: <span data-bind="text: myAreasEditMode"></span><span data-bind="visible: myAreasEditMode">show me</span>
  <br />                  
  not editing (done): <span data-bind="text: (myAreasEditMode == false)"></span><span data-bind="visible: (myAreasEditMode == false)">show me</span>
</div>
```

And the output is:

```
editing: false
not editing (done)?: false
```

Is Knockout manipulating my boolean, or is truthiness confusing me?  I can't figure out why `(myAreasEditMode == false)` returns false, when `myAreasEditMode` is in fact false.

Comment: It looks like I was missing parentheses after myAreasEditMode, so it should be myAreasEditMode().  The parentheses drive me nuts in Knockout!  Sometimes you need them, sometimes you don't, all the time i pull my hair out

Comment: yep. Just wait to you get to the part that knockoutjs parses html comments to bind to array/list in tables with other non-many items. Nice, but a funky learning curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `myAreasEdit` is a function and binding `(myAresEdit == false)` is checking if the Funciton is equal to `false` (which is not true -- a Funciton != false) rather than the value of the function.

The markup should be:

`data-bind="text: (myAreasEditMode() == false)"`